# Random Symphony Exception Drupal 10.1.1 "The theme must be passed as a query argument"

Tags: drupal

I just finished the upgrade of my site from 9.x to 10.1.1.  I am getting random Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\… in the log.  The details of the log messages are

Location: The css file changes with each error.  Sometimes the file exists, and other times it does not.
https://www.hummingbirdhealingcenter.org/sites/default/files/css/css_mBLgU_XxRuPxMwhmPo7QTXj25DV4ZgJnQ7Tq5ihFqP0.css

Referrer:  Sometimes blank, sometimes the url of a site page.  No consistency on which page it is.

Message:    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: The theme must be passed as a query argument in Drupal\system\Controller\AssetControllerBase->deliver() (line 127 of /home/humming7/hhc10/web/core/modules/system/src/Controller/AssetControllerBase.php).

This is all the information I can get.  I have not been able to make the error happen.  Looking at the apache http log at the times the errors are logged reveals no pattern in which page is being requested when the error is logged.

I do not know if this impacts the user experience or not. Any thoughts on what might be happening and how to stop this from occuring?

****   Update after week of observation   ****
This only seems to occur after I have done some edits and clear all caches.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been logged in the Drupal issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3377310. As of this writing, it its status is "Postponed."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "cache error" - something tries to find saved cache css and js files, but fails. Try to:

1. Flush ALL caches via `"drush cr"` or via admin interface;
2. Delete all files in `sites/default/files/css and sites/default/files/js` directories.
3. If this will not help it will be better to create issue on drupal.org. It is a new problem - I've got similar issue after upgrade from `10.0.9 to 10.1.1`.

After doing above steps 1 and 2, I'm waiting if this error will appear again. If not, it is old cache problem, if error will appear, it is a bug and we need to go to step 3.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem as well after Upgrading to Drupal 10.1 yesterday...in debugging I noticed that the aggregated CSS and Javascript files have a query string appended with multiple items. In our case we have a CDN for performance and security reasons and the Web Application Firewall (WAF) provided has a default rule to strip off the query strings for all requests from the general public to prevent certain types of security flaws. It looks like we have to add a query string rule exception to allow those parameters being passed through for sites/default/files/css/* and sites/default/files/js/* .

The change that caused this is described here https://www.drupal.org/node/3301716